# Android how to uncluster on single tap on a cluster marker maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using Google Maps Marker Clustering Utility to cluster the markers. It unclusters on  double tapping. Is it possible to do it manually on single click.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
    mClusterManager
            .setOnClusterClickListener(new OnClusterClickListener<MyItem>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onClusterClick(final Cluster<MyItem> cluster) {
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                            cluster.getPosition(), (float) Math.floor(map
                                    .getCameraPosition().zoom + 1)), 300,
                            null);
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

you can do that on the click of the marker too ,
 but before that you need to do `map.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);`

so that cluster manager gets the click events and 
you can do

```
mClusterManagersetOnClusterItemClickListener(new OnClusterItemClickListener<MyItem>() {

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked! Didn't think of getting the current zoom and incrementing it.

Comment: but does this uncluster "all" the items in cluster? i don't think incrementing zoom by 1 will do it when there is so many cluster items.

Comment: that doesn't answer the question, you can increment zoom in correct ways:
`CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn()`,
`CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo()`,
`CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy()`

Answer (score 54):

Bit late to the party

In your onClusterClick function:

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = LatLngBounds.builder();
for (ClusterItem item : cluster.getItems()) {
    builder.include(item.getPosition());
}
final LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
getMap().animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100));
```

Comment: If the items in cluster have the same Lat Long position, then the map doesn't show the items.

Comment: Hi @Gene, you are correct, but that's an arguable point of UX - how exactly to show 2 items marked at exactly the same point on a map. This question (and answer) is really about pins which are close but not identical and therefore clustered together as one "cluster pin" - those we can uncluster

Answer (score 3):

For those who want to expand the cluster and **KEEP the zoom level**, try the following steps. It seems complicate, but really is not.

## Steps

1. Suppose you have a model called **Location** that implements **ClusterItem**, add following code:

   ```
   private boolean shouldCluster = true;

   public boolean isShouldCluster() {
       return shouldCluster;
   }

   public void setShouldCluster(boolean shouldCluster) {
       this.shouldCluster = shouldCluster;
   }
   ```

   The whole model looks similar to this:

   ```
   public class Location implements ClusterItem
   {
       private double latitude;

       private double longitude;

       private boolean shouldCluster = true;

       @Override
       public LatLng getPosition() {
           return new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
       }

       @Override
       public String getTitle() {
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       public String getSnippet() {
           return null;
       }

       public boolean isShouldCluster() {
           return shouldCluster;
       }

       public void setShouldCluster(boolean shouldCluster) {
           this.shouldCluster = shouldCluster;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add the algorithm below to your project, and replace **Location** with **your own model name**. Note: this algorithm is simply a copy of Google's [NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/algo/NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm.java) with some modifications.

   ```
   public class DistanceBasedAlgorithm implements Algorithm<Location> {
       public static final int MAX_DISTANCE_AT_ZOOM = 100; // essentially 100 dp.

       /**
        * Any modifications should be synchronized on mQuadTree.
        */
       private final Collection<QuadItem> mItems = new ArrayList<QuadItem>();

       /**
        * Any modifications should be synchronized on mQuadTree.
        */
       private final PointQuadTree<QuadItem> mQuadTree = new PointQuadTree<QuadItem>(0, 1, 0, 1);

       private static final SphericalMercatorProjection PROJECTION = new SphericalMercatorProjection(1);

       @Override
       public void addItem(Location item) {
           if (item == null) return;

           final QuadItem quadItem = new QuadItem(item);
           synchronized (mQuadTree) {
               mItems.add(quadItem);
               mQuadTree.add(quadItem);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void addItems(Collection<Location> items) {
           for (Location item : items) {
               addItem(item);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void clearItems() {
           synchronized (mQuadTree) {
               mItems.clear();
               mQuadTree.clear();
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void removeItem(Location item) {
           // QuadItem delegates hashcode() and equals() to its item so,
           //   removing any QuadItem to that item will remove the item
           final QuadItem quadItem = new QuadItem(item);
           synchronized (mQuadTree) {
               mItems.remove(quadItem);
               mQuadTree.remove(quadItem);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public Set<? extends Cluster<Location>> getClusters(double zoom) {
           final int discreteZoom = (int) zoom;

           final double zoomSpecificSpan = MAX_DISTANCE_AT_ZOOM / Math.pow(2, discreteZoom) / 256;

           final Set<QuadItem> visitedCandidates = new HashSet<QuadItem>();
           final Set<Cluster<Location>> results = new HashSet<Cluster<Location>>();
           final Map<QuadItem, Double> distanceToCluster = new HashMap<QuadItem, Double>();
           final Map<QuadItem, StaticCluster<Location>> itemToCluster = new HashMap<QuadItem, StaticCluster<Location>>();

           synchronized (mQuadTree) {
               for (QuadItem candidate : mItems) {
                   if (visitedCandidates.contains(candidate)) {
                       // Candidate is already part of another cluster.
                       continue;
                   }

                   Collection<QuadItem> clusterItems;

                   if (candidate.mClusterItem.isShouldCluster()) {
                       Bounds searchBounds = createBoundsFromSpan(candidate.getPoint(), zoomSpecificSpan);
                       clusterItems = mQuadTree.search(searchBounds);
                   }
                   else {
                       List<QuadItem> temp = new ArrayList<>();
                       temp.add(candidate);
                       clusterItems = temp;
                   }

                   if (clusterItems.size() == 1) {
                       // Only the current marker is in range. Just add the single item to the results.
                       results.add(candidate);
                       visitedCandidates.add(candidate);
                       distanceToCluster.put(candidate, 0d);
                       continue;
                   }
                   StaticCluster<Location> cluster = new StaticCluster<Location>(candidate.mClusterItem.getPosition());
                   results.add(cluster);

                   for (QuadItem clusterItem : clusterItems) {
                       Double existingDistance = distanceToCluster.get(clusterItem);
                       double distance = distanceSquared(clusterItem.getPoint(), candidate.getPoint());
                       if (existingDistance != null) {
                           // Item already belongs to another cluster. Check if it's closer to this cluster.
                           if (existingDistance < distance) {
                               continue;
                           }
                           // Move item to the closer cluster.
                           itemToCluster.get(clusterItem).remove(clusterItem.mClusterItem);
                       }
                       distanceToCluster.put(clusterItem, distance);
                       cluster.add(clusterItem.mClusterItem);
                       itemToCluster.put(clusterItem, cluster);
                   }
                   visitedCandidates.addAll(clusterItems);
               }
           }
           return results;
       }

       @Override
       public Collection<Location> getItems() {
           final List<Location> items = new ArrayList<Location>();
           synchronized (mQuadTree) {
               for (QuadItem quadItem : mItems) {
                   items.add(quadItem.mClusterItem);
               }
           }
           return items;
       }

       private double distanceSquared(Point a, Point b) {
           return (a.x - b.x) * (a.x - b.x) + (a.y - b.y) * (a.y - b.y);
       }

       private Bounds createBoundsFromSpan(Point p, double span) {
           // TODO: Use a span that takes into account the visual size of the marker, not just its
           // LatLng.
           double halfSpan = span / 2;
           return new Bounds(
                   p.x - halfSpan, p.x + halfSpan,
                   p.y - halfSpan, p.y + halfSpan);
       }

       private static class QuadItem implements PointQuadTree.Item, Cluster<Location> {
           private final Location mClusterItem;
           private final Point mPoint;
           private final LatLng mPosition;
           private Set<Location> singletonSet;

           private QuadItem(Location item) {
               mClusterItem = item;
               mPosition = item.getPosition();
               mPoint = PROJECTION.toPoint(mPosition);
               singletonSet = Collections.singleton(mClusterItem);
           }

           @Override
           public Point getPoint() {
               return mPoint;
           }

           @Override
           public LatLng getPosition() {
               return mPosition;
           }

           @Override
           public Set<Location> getItems() {
               return singletonSet;
           }

           @Override
           public int getSize() {
               return 1;
           }

           @Override
           public int hashCode() {
               return mClusterItem.hashCode();
           }

           @Override
           public boolean equals(Object other) {
               if (!(other instanceof QuadItem)) {
                   return false;
               }

               return ((QuadItem) other).mClusterItem.equals(mClusterItem);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Setup algorithm and cluster click listener

   ```
   map.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
   mClusterManager.setAlgorithm(new DistanceBasedAlgorithm());
   mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<Location>() {
               @Override
               public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<Location> cluster) {
                   for (Location location : cluster.getItems()) {
                       location.setShouldCluster(false);
                   }
                   mClusterManager.addItem(null); // this line resets the cache
                   mClusterManager.cluster(); // re-cluster

                   return false;
               }
           });
   ```
4. Done!

---

## Explanation

A little explanation of how does the DistanceBasedAlgorithm enable uncluster

1. In **getClusters** function, the snippet below checks whether the item should be cluster

   ```
           if (candidate.mClusterItem.isShouldCluster()) {
               Bounds searchBounds = createBoundsFromSpan(candidate.getPoint(), zoomSpecificSpan);
               clusterItems = mQuadTree.search(searchBounds);
           }
           else {
               List<QuadItem> temp = new ArrayList<>();
               temp.add(candidate);
               clusterItems = temp;
           }
   ```
2. The changes of **addItem** function, allows the algorithm to accept a null value, thereby allows [PreCachingAlgorithmDecorator](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/algo/PreCachingAlgorithmDecorator.java) to clear cache.

   ```
   @Override
   public void addItem(Location item) {
       if (item == null) return; // this line is the key to reset cache

       final QuadItem quadItem = new QuadItem(item);
       synchronized (mQuadTree) {
           mItems.add(quadItem);
           mQuadTree.add(quadItem);
       }
   }
   ```

It's been a while since I wrote the code. I might miss something. Leave me a comment if you have trouble to make this solution work. Thanks!

Comment: How to enable cluster again? You setShouldCluster(false) after clicking on cluster, but how to enable it on map scroll or any other actions?

Comment: @NickUnuchek it's been awhile. I can't remember the detail. I believe DistanceBasedAlgorithm.getClusters recreates all the items, which defaults shouldCluster to true, when actions are applied. In our product, we don't have any issues for reclustering.